# CS7036:There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'i'

Tags: c#, inheritance, parameters, constructor, public

I am just learning C#, and I made two external classes with constructors, and one inherits from another one. But it is giving the Error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'i' of 'Engineer.Engineer(string)' program.cs  C:\Users\win 10\Desktop\C#\program.cs\program.cs\Car.cs 41  Active
The Three Code files are:
1/ main.cs:

```
using System;

namespace program
{
    class Core
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car BMW = new Car("X-A-21-A-X", 3200000, "Reddish-brown", false);
            string currentPrice = BMW.CheckPrice("us", BMW.price);
            if(!double.TryParse(currentPrice, out var q))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(currentPrice);
            }else if(double.TryParse(currentPrice, out var z))
            {
                double converted_Price = Convert.ToDouble(currentPrice);
                Console.WriteLine(converted_Price);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(BMW.model);
        }
    }
}
```

2/ Car.cs:

```
using System;
namespace program
{
    class Car : Engineer
    {
        private string _model;
        public string model
        {
            get { return _model; }
            set { _model = value; }
        }
        public double price;
        public string color;
        public bool available;
        public string CheckPrice(string locale, double price)
        {
            string ret = default(string);
            if(locale == "in")// India
            {
                ret = Convert.ToString(2.14 * price);
            }else if(locale == "us")// USA
            {
                ret = Convert.ToString(3.98 * price);
            }else if(locale == "jp")// Japan
            {
                ret = Convert.ToString(1.3 * price);
            }else if(locale == "vn")//Vietnam
            {
                ret = Convert.ToString(0.78645 * price);
            }else if(locale == "ch")//China
            {
                ret = Convert.ToString(2.56 * price);
            }
            else
            {
                ret = "Invalid Locale, Your Country does not ship the car.";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(_model);
            return ret;
        }
        public Car(string modelName, double priceVal, string ColorName, bool avail) /* 'Car' in this line is causing problems*/
        {
            model = modelName;
            price = priceVal;
            color = ColorName;
            available = avail;
        }
    }
}
```

3/ Engineer.cs:

```
using System;

namespace program
{
    class Engineer
    {
        private string creatorCompany;
        public string creator_Company
        {
            get { return creatorCompany; }
            set { creatorCompany = value; }
        }
        public Engineer(string i)
        {
            creator_Company = i;
        }
    }
}
```

There are answers there but I can't understand them. Please explain them to me like I'm a monke who doesn't know sh*t

Comment: try adding default constructor in Engineer class `public Engineer()
        {
        }`

Comment: @viveknuna I have that added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor of the child class you must reference the parameters of the parent/base class.
In this case change the constructor of the Car class to the following.

```
//Inside class Car
public Car(string i, string modelName, double priceVal, string ColorName, bool avail) : base(i)
{
//Code inside
}
```

This is all that cause an issue not anything else.

Comment: Car **being** an engineer is strange.

Comment: I was just learning C#, and just experimenting

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the default constructor to the `Engineer` class. because when you create an instance of derived it calls the base class constructor before the derived class constructor.

```
public Engineer()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## If `Car` is `Engineer`

In the unlikely scenario that `Car` is `Engineer` the `Car` needs to supply `creatorCompany`:

1. `Engineer` definition states that `creatorCompany` must be supplied
2. `Car` *is* `Engineer`
3. `Car` must provide `creatorCompany`.

It could look something like this:

```
public Car(
  string creatorCompany, // Added
  string modelName, 
  double priceVal, 
  string ColorName, 
  bool avail) 
: base(i: creatorCompany) // Added
{
   model = modelName;
   price = priceVal;
   color = ColorName;
   available = avail;
}
```

## If `Car` is not `Engineer`

In this case, the solution is to remove `: Engineer`:

```
class Car : Engineer
```

becomes:

```
class Car
```